# Calculate broadcast addres from cidr

Tags: cidr

Is it possible to calculate the broadcast ip address from the cidr address format (e.g 198.0.0.1/8) only.Or do i have to add the subnet mask.If you have a script that can do that please share

Comment: If you are looking for help with creating a program to perform these calculations, please share the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

The subnet mask is already expressed by the suffix (/8 in your example corresponds to 255.0.0.0).  The last address of the CIDR range is the broadcast address (so 192.255.255.255 in your case).

(The .1 at the end is masked out by the /8 so isn't really correct.  The correct canonical form of your CIDR expression is 198.0.0.0/8.)